# Passing a java list to an html template

Tags: java, html, playframework

I have a printed export from an html file that it takes imports from a Map as shown below

```
Template t = TemplateLoader.load("Printing/acount.html");
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("accountName ", e.accountName);
map.put("accountAmount ", acAmount);
    return t.render(map);
```

And loads the parametres to the html file

```
<div>
     Account: <font size="3"><b>${ accountName }</b> ${accountAmount}</font> <br/>
```

And its export looks like

Account 15884    5.000

What if I want to have multiple records in my export?

Lets say

Account 15885    2.000

Account 15886    4.000

Account 15887    3.000

How should be the html and java code in the second case in order to pas an uknown number of records?

Comment: Maybe you should tell us which template engine/API you're using.

Comment: SOrry I am ussing play framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now creating a `Map` with values for `accountName` and `accountAmount`. What you should do is add a list of objects that each contain a value for `accountName` and `accountAmount`.

It would look something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
map.put("accounts", accounts);
return t.render(map);
```

In your template you can then iterate over the items in `${ accounts }` (e.g., for each `account` in `accounts`) and print each value of `account.name` and `account.amount`.

I'm not familiar with the exact syntax of these templates but the approach should be along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you have List, you can do

```
map.put("accounts", theAccountList);
```

In the template (which I assume is FreeMarker) you do:

```
<#list accounts as account>
 <div>Account: <font size="3"><b>${account.getName()}</b> ${account.getAmount()}</font> <br/></div>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list and a for loop. Look up JSP or JSTL for loop.

Comment: the OP was talking about playframework, JSP and JSTL aren't used.